# Index value wont Increase after comparing two chars

Tags: java, indexing, char

I started this because I was totally bored but because of this error I have been sitting here since so long and finally decided to take this to stackOverFlow. Here is the code Which I wrote.

I was trying to print characters by skipping 1 index. But when there are duplicates I want to print a space which would differentitate words from big string.

Updated Question: Everything fixed except I cant increase I value more than 1. I commented it in below program. Please look at it.

Let me cut the chase and get to the point. I need this output " Vishnu Vardhan" from this String  "aVeIwSjHaNgUaaVdAgRjDkHxAmN";

My only requirement is if the string has two same letters it has to print space. So "aVeIwSjHaNgU [aa] VdAgRjDkHxAmN" the aa in the brackets has to be replaced by space.

It has to be dynamic, if any char is repeated it has to print a space and jump to required next char and print it.

Here is the Updated program. Using help from one of the comments.

public class Decrypter {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Text = "aVeIwSjHaNgUaaVdAgRjDkHxAmN";
    char[] convertedText = Text.toCharArray();//converted string to char array

    for (int i = 1; i < convertedText.length; i++) { //Looping it to print alternate chars

        /* if the character at an index is same as the character at next index then
         add a space and increase index value by 2 so I can print the required char*/
        if (i + 1 < convertedText.length) {
            if (Text.charAt(i) == Text.charAt(i + 1)) {

                i++;// Increasing I value by 2 here will give me required output. Everything is perfect now

                System.out.printf("%s ", convertedText[i]);
            } else {
                System.out.printf("%s", convertedText[i]);
                i++;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Current output : VISHNUadgjkxm

Required output: VISHNU VARDHAN

Comment: What is the expected output for that input? I don't entirely understand what your requirements are.

Comment: What are you hoping `System.out.printf(" %s", args)` will do?

Comment: and starting the loop with a value of 1. you will never get the first char in your char array.

Comment: @Secondo We're not sure he wants the first character in his array.  Actually, at this point, we don't know what he wants at all.

Comment: i understand what he wants. he want to make an output like this `aVeIwSjHaNgUk kVarqdlhxn` `if(char1 == char2) if true add space then print the char2.

Comment: `string.replaceAll("(.)\\1", "$1 $1")`

Comment: @MikeKobit I was trying to print a long string encrypted with set of different letters but in a format

Comment: @Secondo Yes, first letter always has to be ignored

Comment: @ajb Sorry If I was not clear in my question. I am clear with what i want and there few friends here already answered it, thanks for comment

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if converting string to charArray is required but i hope this will do. comment below if you have questions open for revision.

```
    String text = "aVeIwSjjHaNgUkkVarqddlhxn";
    //this is the holder of your new processed text.
    String newText = "";

    //start of counter. it may start in any number depends on requirements.
    int x = 0;

    //loop while the x is lessthan the length of your string.
    while(x < text.length()){

        //check if the x + 1 is not equal to the length of your string to avoid StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
        if((x+1) != text.length()){

            //in this area it will check if the current char is the same on next index
            if(text.charAt(x) == text.charAt(x+1)){

                // this will concatenate/append the value of char with space 
                newText += text.charAt(x) +" ";
                // this will increase the value of your x by 1 and at the bottom there are also x++ that will add 1 to your x so the total sum of x if (text.charAt(x) == text.charAt(x+1)) are true, will be 2.
                x++;
            }

        }
        newText += text.charAt(x);
        x++;
    }
    System.out.println(newText);
```

output :

```
aVeIwSj jHaNgUk kVarqd dlhxn
```

if this is not what you looking for please kindly update your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Thats not what I am looking for but based on your comments I will try and figure out. if I cant get I will update my question.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
/**
 *
 * @author Chintu
 */
public class Decrypter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Text = "aVeIwSjHaNgUkkVarqdlhxn";
    char[] convertedText = Text.toCharArray();//converted string to char array

    for (int i = 1; i < convertedText.length; i++) { //Looping it to print alternate chars

        /* if the character at an index is same as the character at next index then
         add a space and increase index value by 2 so I can print the required char*/
        if (i+1 < convertedText.length) {
            if (Text.charAt(i) == Text.charAt(i + 1)) {
                i++;
                System.out.printf("%s ",convertedText[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%s", convertedText[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. it fixed the space but its not totally decrypting the string.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

public class Decrypter {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Text = "aVeIwSjHaNgUaaVdAgRjDkHxAmN";
    char[] convertedText = Text.toCharArray();//converted string to char array

    for (int i = 0; i < convertedText.length; i++) { //Looping it to print alternate chars

        /* if the character at an index is same as the character at next index then
         add a space and increase index value by 2 so I can print the required char*/
        if (i + 1 < convertedText.length) {
            if (Text.charAt(i) == Text.charAt(i + 1)) {

                i += 2;   
                System.out.printf(" %s", convertedText[i]);
            } else {
                i++;
                System.out.printf("%s", convertedText[i]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

output: VISHNU VARDHAN